# Checking that a filename matches a pattern within a tar --to-command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a TGZ file (compressed with GZIP) that contains a wide variety of other compressed files, some binary, some ascii text.  I would like to grep through the compressed ascii text files looking for string matches and print the filename.  Some research has brought me to the `tar --to-command`, which seems to almost do exactly what I want when executed with `zgrep`, however, I cannot filter out which file names to search for so task takes prohibitively long and prints out some garbage along the way.

This does what I want except it examines all files in the archive:

```
tar xaPf log.tgz --to-command='zgrep -l "mystring" && echo $TAR_FILENAME || true'
```

This was my best guess at how to do it:

```
tar xaPf log.tgz --to-command='if [[ $TAR_FILENAME *asciiFile.gz ]]; then zgrep 'mystring'; fi'
```

But all I get is this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
```

For every file.  From what I have read, the arguments for the `--to-command` do not run in a full bash shell, so what conditional statement can I do so that I only evaluate files of a given suffix?  Thanks

---

Update:
Realizing that `--to-command` only executes `/bin/sh` shell commands, I revised my command:

```
tar xaPf log.tgz --to-command='[ "$TAR_FILENAME" = "*asciiFile.gz" ] && zgrep "mystring" || true'
```

So now it execute without errors, but the conditional expression is never true.  How can I check for a pattern in `/bin/sh`?

Comment: `[[` is a `bash` extension, `--to-command` uses `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`.

Comment: A better solution might be to use [archivemount](https://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount.html). This allows you to mount a tar file as a filesystem, so you can access the contents as a directory.

Comment: Very useful, I'd never heard of archivemount, that will help me out going forward as I frequently work with very large archives.

Comment: If you use Emacs, you can also load a tar file into a buffer, and it will display it like Dired.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
tar xaPf log.tgz --to-command='echo "$TAR_FILENAME" | grep -q "asciiFile.gz" && zgrep "mystring" || true'
```